# Change list into dataframe without loop R

Tags: r, loops, sapply

I have Large list `city` of 16 elements. Each element represents different city but despite that the structure is the same.

```
head(city[[1]])
     Time       CET          Date       Region       Temp.      Windchill  Dew.Point  Humidity   Pressure  
[1,] Numeric,24 Character,24 Numeric,24 Character,24 Logical,24 Logical,24 Logical,24 Logical,24 Logical,24
[2,] Numeric,24 Character,24 Numeric,24 Character,24 Logical,24 Logical,24 Logical,24 Logical,24 Logical,24
[3,] Numeric,24 Character,24 Numeric,24 Character,24 Logical,24 Logical,24 Logical,24 Logical,24 Logical,24
[4,] Numeric,24 Character,24 Numeric,24 Character,24 Logical,24 Logical,24 Logical,24 Logical,24 Logical,24
[5,] Numeric,24 Character,24 Numeric,24 Character,24 Logical,24 Logical,24 Logical,24 Logical,24 Logical,24
[6,] Numeric,24 Character,24 Numeric,24 Character,24 Logical,24 Logical,24 Logical,24 Logical,24 Logical,24
     Visibility Wind.Dir   Wind.Speed
[1,] Logical,24 Logical,24 Logical,24
[2,] Logical,24 Logical,24 Logical,24
[3,] Logical,24 Logical,24 Logical,24
[4,] Logical,24 Logical,24 Logical,24
[5,] Logical,24 Logical,24 Logical,24
[6,] Logical,24 Logical,24 Logical,24
```

`dput(city[[1]][1:6,])`:

```
structure(list(c(12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), c(12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), c(12, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11), c(12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), c(12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), c(12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), 
    c("AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", 
    "AM", "AM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", 
    "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM"), c("AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", 
    "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "PM", "PM", "PM", 
    "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM"), c("AM", 
    "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", 
    "AM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", 
    "PM", "PM", "PM"), c("AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", 
    "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", 
    "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM"), c("AM", 
    "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", 
    "AM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", 
    "PM", "PM", "PM"), c("AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", 
    "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", 
    "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM", "PM"), structure(c(15705, 
    15705, 15705, 15705, 15705, 15705, 15705, 15705, 15705, 15705, 
    15705, 15705, 15705, 15705, 15705, 15705, 15705, 15705, 15705, 
    15705, 15705, 15705, 15705, 15705), class = "Date"), structure(c(15706, 
    15706, 15706, 15706, 15706, 15706, 15706, 15706, 15706, 15706, 
    15706, 15706, 15706, 15706, 15706, 15706, 15706, 15706, 15706, 
    15706, 15706, 15706, 15706, 15706), class = "Date"), structure(c(15707, 
    15707, 15707, 15707, 15707, 15707, 15707, 15707, 15707, 15707, 
    15707, 15707, 15707, 15707, 15707, 15707, 15707, 15707, 15707, 
    15707, 15707, 15707, 15707, 15707), class = "Date"), structure(c(15708, 
    15708, 15708, 15708, 15708, 15708, 15708, 15708, 15708, 15708, 
    15708, 15708, 15708, 15708, 15708, 15708, 15708, 15708, 15708, 
    15708, 15708, 15708, 15708, 15708), class = "Date"), structure(c(15709, 
    15709, 15709, 15709, 15709, 15709, 15709, 15709, 15709, 15709, 
    15709, 15709, 15709, 15709, 15709, 15709, 15709, 15709, 15709, 
    15709, 15709, 15709, 15709, 15709), class = "Date"), structure(c(15710, 
    15710, 15710, 15710, 15710, 15710, 15710, 15710, 15710, 15710, 
    15710, 15710, 15710, 15710, 15710, 15710, 15710, 15710, 15710, 
    15710, 15710, 15710, 15710, 15710), class = "Date"), c("EPWR", 
    "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", 
    "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", 
    "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR"), 
    c("EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", 
    "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", 
    "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", 
    "EPWR"), c("EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", 
    "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", 
    "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", 
    "EPWR", "EPWR"), c("EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", 
    "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", 
    "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", 
    "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR"), c("EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", 
    "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", 
    "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", 
    "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR"), c("EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", 
    "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", 
    "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", 
    "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR", "EPWR"), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Dim = c(6L, 
12L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Time", "CET", "Date", "Region", 
"Temp.", "Windchill", "Dew.Point", "Humidity", "Pressure", "Visibility", 
"Wind.Dir", "Wind.Speed")))
```

How it should look in the end:

```
    Time CET       Date Region Temp. Windchill Dew.Point Humidity Pressure Visibility Wind.Dir Wind.Speed
1   12  AM 2012-12-31   EPWR    NA        NA        NA       NA       NA         NA       NA         NA
2    1  AM 2012-12-31   EPWR    NA        NA        NA       NA       NA         NA       NA         NA
3    2  AM 2012-12-31   EPWR    NA        NA        NA       NA       NA         NA       NA         NA
4    3  AM 2012-12-31   EPWR    NA        NA        NA       NA       NA         NA       NA         NA
5    4  AM 2012-12-31   EPWR    NA        NA        NA       NA       NA         NA       NA         NA
6    5  AM 2012-12-31   EPWR    NA        NA        NA       NA       NA         NA       NA         NA
```

I would like to covert this list into one row binded dataframe without using loops. 
I came up with that approach but it involves loops.

```
  data_whole <- list()
  data <- data.frame()

  for(i in 1:length(city)){
    for(j in 1:nrow(city[[i]])){
      data<- bind_rows(data, data.frame(city[[i]][j,]))
    }
    data_whole[[i]] <- data
  }
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `dput` data showed is just one `list` element, we created a `list` with 2 such elements and used `rbindlist`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(city, function(x) data.frame(lapply(as.data.frame(x), unlist))))
```

---

Or `tidyverse` to get the expected output

```
library(tidyverse)
city %>% 
     map(as.tibble) %>% 
     bind_rows %>%
     unnest
# A tibble: 288 × 12
#    Time   CET       Date Region Temp. Windchill Dew.Point Humidity Pressure Visibility Wind.Dir Wind.Speed
#   <dbl> <chr>     <date>  <chr> <lgl>     <lgl>     <lgl>    <lgl>    <lgl>      <lgl>    <lgl>      <lgl>
#1     12    AM 2012-12-31   EPWR    NA        NA        NA       NA       NA         NA       NA         NA
#2      1    AM 2012-12-31   EPWR    NA        NA        NA       NA       NA         NA       NA         NA
#3      2    AM 2012-12-31   EPWR    NA        NA        NA       NA       NA         NA       NA         NA
#4      3    AM 2012-12-31   EPWR    NA        NA        NA       NA       NA         NA       NA         NA
#5      4    AM 2012-12-31   EPWR    NA        NA        NA       NA       NA         NA       NA         NA
#6      5    AM 2012-12-31   EPWR    NA        NA        NA       NA       NA         NA       NA         NA
#7      6    AM 2012-12-31   EPWR    NA        NA        NA       NA       NA         NA       NA         NA
#8      7    AM 2012-12-31   EPWR    NA        NA        NA       NA       NA         NA       NA         NA
#9      8    AM 2012-12-31   EPWR    NA        NA        NA       NA       NA         NA       NA         NA
#10     9    AM 2012-12-31   EPWR    NA        NA        NA       NA       NA         NA       NA         NA
# ... with 278 more rows
```

#### data

```
city <- list(city1, city1)
```

Comment: @piotr Thanks, I modified the syntax to make it more `tidy` :-)